# How to show messages depending of the program's nature

Tags: c#

Please, sorry for the long text.

I have a library of C# Classes which retrieves information from various systems, invokes external functions, validates this info and generates results of the validation to a file. This library can  indistinctly be invoked from: 1) a DOS console program, 2) from a Windows form or 3) from a windows service program.

Users have asked me for modifying the library so it can run in a verbose way, i.e. to show the date and time at certain steps, to briefly explain what a certain step or method is doing, etc. They also asked me for introducing exception handling and show error messages.

If I execute in console mode, I should show the messages on the console, if I execute from a Windows form I should send the messages to a message box or to a text box, and if I run from a Windows Service I should send the messages to a log file.

I have 2 questions:

1)  How should I modify the C# Classes so I can avoid the constant evaluation:
If program is in console mode writeline…..
Else if program is in windows forms mode messagebox or textbox.text …
Else if program is invoked from a windows service program writelogfile….

2)  If the above evaluation  is unavoidable, how can I know if the library of C# classes is being invoked by a console, windows form  windows service program?

Thanks!!

---

Possible solution:

---

I read a little about MS Enterprise Library and ... it is too much for my modest requirement so I went for the pragmatic solution of Reed.

I share the way I solved the user requirements, it is a preliminary model before applying to the real situation so, before accepting the Reed solution, your comments to improve and learn are really welcome.

1) I created a little library to define all possible outputs, in this case I defined only the outputs to a console and to a WPF form:

namespace diClass
{
    public interface IVerbose
    {
        void show(string msg, object textBox);
        void notify(string msg);
    }

```
public class ConsoleOutput : IVerbose
{
    public void show(string msg, object textBox)
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine(msg);
    }

    public void notify(string msg)
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine("Notif: " + msg);           
    }

}

public class WpfOutput : IVerbose
{
    public void show(string msg, object textBox)
    {
        TextBox tb = (TextBox)textBox;
        tb.Text += msg + "\r\n";
        System.Windows.Forms.Application.DoEvents();
    }
    public void notify(string msg)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(msg);
    }
}

public class Output
{
    IVerbose outputType;

    public IVerbose verboseType
    {
        get { return outputType; }
        set { outputType = value; }
    }

    public void show(string msg, object textBox)
    {
        outputType.show(msg, textBox);
    }

    public void notify(string msg)
    {
        outputType.notify(msg);
    }
}
```

}

2) Then I defined a console program which uses the above library:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        IVerbose verboseType = (IVerbose)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(diClass.ConsoleOutput));
        Output o = new Output();
        o.verboseType = verboseType;
        object textBox1 = null;
        o.show(string.Format("{0}: Reading Accountig data", DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yy hh:mm:ss")), textBox1);
        o.notify(string.Format("{0}: Application error", DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yy hh:mm:ss")));
    }
}
```

3) Finally I defined a WPF program which also uses the above library:

```
public partial class Window1 : Window
{
    public Window1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        IVerbose verboseType = (IVerbose)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(diClass.WpfOutput));
        Output o = new Output();
        o.verboseType = verboseType;
        o.show(string.Format("{0}: Reading Accountig data", DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yy hh:mm:ss")), textBox1);
        o.notify(string.Format("{0}: Application error", DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yy hh:mm:ss")));
    }
}
```

In programs 2) and 3) the last two lines of code are equal, there is no *ifs* and, that is what I wanted as answer.

Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My preference, for this type of situation, is to make a set of interfaces, and work against the interfaces.  You can then use Dependency Injection to inject a concrete version of the interface depending on whether you're running in console, gui, or as a service.  Something like (this is a very simple version):

```
public interface IAlgorithm
{
    void UpdateProgress(double percent);
    void Complete(bool success);
    void Error(string error); // Or (Exception error), if you want to pass an exception
}
public interface IAlgorithmFactory
{
    IAlgorithm StartAlgorithm(string name);
}
```

Then, let's take the console application version.  You just need to provide the correct `IAlgorithmFactory` for a console app:

```
class ConsoleAlgorithm : IAlgorithm
{
    string name;
    public ConsoleAlgorithm(string algorithmName)
    { 
        this.name = algorithmName;
    }
    public void UpdateProgress(double percent)
    {
        if(percent == 0)
            Console.WriteLine();
        else if (percent == 1.0)
            Console.WriteLine("100%        ");
        else
            Console.Write("\r{0}%", percent * 100);
    }
    public void Complete(bool success)
    {
        if (success)
            Console.WriteLine("{0} completed successfully.", this.name);
        else
            Console.WriteLine("{0} failed.");
    }
    public void Error(string error)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0} received error: {1}", this.name, error);
    }
}

public class ConsoleAlgorithmFactory: IAlgorithmFactory
{
    public IAlgorithm StartAlgorithm(string name)
    {
        return new ConsoleAlgorithm(name);
    }
}
```

When your program runs as a console, you'd provide it a `ConsoleAlgorithmFactory`, and it would just use it as an `IAlgorithmFactory`.  You can call the methods on it to report progress, and your main program doesn't care how it's run - it just reports as needed.

When you run as a GUI, on the other hand, you'd make something like `WindowsFormsAlgorithmFactory`, pass it in, and now the reporting would be done via forms... Nothing in your program changes.

Comment: What benefit would this have over using events? In your model if somebody didn't want to listen to certain actions, you would have degenerate methods. You could create an interface for every method, but it seems like this is already built into events.

Comment: You can pass a lot more information in a very rich fashion, more simply than using events. Granted, in this situation (what I posted), events would work as well. The other "problem" with events is that events are subscriber based - so the "forms" need to know about, understand, and have access to the program internals, at least the portions with the events. That can be simple, but can also be (in some cases) difficult and require major api changes. This is more push based - the "logic" in the program just says "I want to do this", and it's up to the presentation to decide whether to handle it.

Comment: It really comes down to whether you want the outside world to need to know about your algorithm (in which events, ie: the observer pattern makes sense), or you want your logic to work, and be able to create "reporting" or "gui" classes without knowing what concrete version is being used, which is what I did (abstract factory pattern).  This is one situation where you could use either approach - it just depends on how much information you are passing, how you want to structure your API, and where you want to introduce the abstraction levels.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean when you say you can pass more information? I believe events would work better in this case because you have many subscribers and a single service. From a maintenance standpoint, if you were using interfaces, adding another method would require either changes to each UI or creating another interface to handle it. In the case of events, just add another event and allow the UI that needs it to add a delegate to it. Maybe I don't see the hardship of adding exposed events over having a constructor which takes an interface and passes it down.

Comment: I could see how the service could dictate the UI by enforcing the UI to implement a certain interface. But I do like the observer pattern.

Comment: Events work well for this, as well.  As I said, it's two different approaches.  The problem with events is more a matter of scope - if the class that's raising the event isn't something that's part of your public API, you have to expose it (and expose a way to get the appropriate reference to that instance).  This may be simple, if your "logic" is a single instance of a single class, but if it's in a class created by a class created by your instance of the class at the top level, all of those other classes now need to be discoverable by the subscribers, etc.

Comment: Using the observer pattern forces you to expose more of your internals - which is the downside of it.  Also, using my approach lets the subscriber manage state in a simple way, but also lets you expose a potentially large API.  The downside to my approach is every "subscriber" needs to implement the entire factory (although using a base class with empty implementations instead of an interface can mitigate that requirement completely).

Comment: Reed, I am trying to solve my problem by applying your tips. I espect not to be wrong but when I try to develop the WindowsFormsAlgorithmFactory into my common C# library of classes, I need to use Windows.Forms.... components, however the Visual Studio does not let me to expose them, any ideas please?

Comment: @Tristan: Make sure, in the assembly where you're defining that, to reference System.Windows.Forms.dll.  You probably don't have a reference there - if you do, you should be able to use them as much as needed.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of trying to handle all these conditions, have considered adding logging  (e.g [Enterprise Library Logging Application Block](http://www.codeplex.com/entlib) or any other logging tool) that writes verbose logs, this will help you satisfy all your requirements, i.e. timestamping, method execution information, exceptions, errors.

Comment: This probably is less-than-ideal for the GUI situation, but perfect for console + service.

Answer (score 0):

Have an event which displays messages/alerting in case of exceptions.

```
public event Action<string> Message;
```

Allowing any UI that wants to do something with that message, just add its own delegate.